# Color change in toc \addcontentsline shows up in pdf bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color, pdf, bookmarks

I want to change the color of one of the lines in my toc. I have a lot of very specific formatting so in order to add a link in my table of contents I am using the `\addcontents` command.

```
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{238, 50, 36}  

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\color{Red}{United States}}
```

This works as expected and I get that line to show up red. An unanticipated effect, however is that "RedUnited States", rather than "United States" appears in the pdf bookmarks document hierarchy.

Is there a way to change the color using `\addcontents` line without this happening?

note: I am using the `tocloft` package.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Either use `\textcolor` as in jfbu's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427048/16967) or disable `\color` in bookmarks:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \def\color#1#{\@gobble}%
}
```

`#1` catches all up to the next open curly brace, the optional argument of `\color`. Then `\@gobble` removes the mandatory argument of `\color`.

Comment: What is the other `#` for then?

Comment: @daleif The end token for `#1`, the left curly brace (category code 1).

Comment: Oh, need to brush up on some tex rules

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the log to confirm something went wrong:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 7.
```

(the line number tells you were in the source)

The correct macro is `\textcolor`, not `\color`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, hyperref}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{238, 50, 36}  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{foo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textcolor{Red}{United States}}
\section{bar}
\end{document}
```

(it undergoes some expansion when written to the `.toc` file but that does not matter here; you could have used  `\protect\color` but that it works without coloring other material is related to extra groups added by other macros, it is luck. And the braces around `United States` in OP's code serve nothing as it is not argument of `\color` command. Better to use `\textcolor`.)

Comment: thanks! changing \color to \textcolor did exactly what I needed.

Comment: /color worked as expected and didn't produce any errors (so there was no need to look in the log file -- unless you are saying that it should've produced the warning you pasted?), can you clarify what you mean by 'not scoped'.

Comment: ok, I had forgotten that `\l@section` introduces a group level, so `\color` is scoped from that (meaning that its effect is local to a certain context). Additionnally as hyperref converts the section title into an hyperlink in toc, it may add its own additional scope. So I will remove my comment from my answer. If you use `\color{Red}{foo}` in normal text, you will see that effect of `\color` is not extinguished and the braces around `foo` serve nothing as it is not fetched as argument. The correct macro is `\textcolor`. You can use `\protect\color` in your code.