# Label reference somehow appears in PDF bookmark; how to get rid?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

The following code produces the following PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true] {hyperref}
\begin{document}

\part{\label{blah}Hi}

\section{Answers to Part \hyperref[blah]{Hehehe}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure why "[blah]" somehow appears in the PDF bookmark. How do I get rid of it?

[I'm using hyperref because I want to have any arbitrary text (e.g. "Hehehe") for my hyperlink.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote, in a comment on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441696/5001):

> I want to use `\hyperref` so I can put arbitrary text for my hyperlink.

You could use the `\texorpdfstring` macro.

[image]

It's not possible to have general hyperlinks in the Bookmarks portion of the pdf document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true] {hyperref}
\begin{document}
\part{Hi} \label{blah}
\section{Answers to \texorpdfstring{\hyperref[blah]{Part I}}{\autoref{blah}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you use `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true] {hyperref}
\begin{document}

\part{Hi}
\label{blah}

\section{Answers to Part \ref{blah}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to use hyperref so I can put arbitrary text for my hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Or based on [this answer by Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427049/43317):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true] {hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \def\hyperref#1#{}%
}
\begin{document}
\part{\label{blah}Hi}
\section{Answers to \hyperref[blah]{Part I}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but I don't understand it fully and I'm worried there may be side effects especially if I declare it globally.